# Unable to override to fix the dimension of the column?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to fix the column size ie) col class. Currently below are the following properties:

```
.col {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    display: block;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I tried like below,

```
#id .col {
    flex: none !important;
    width: 45px !important;
}
```

This works perfectly in browser and portrait resolution of screen.
[image]

However it not fixing the width for landscape resolution. 
[image]

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code, but it looks like the icon is floated left in the first/portrait case and displayed as inline/inline-block in the second/landscape case.  I would look at any media queries to see how the display property is being used.

Comment: CSS code without the corresponding HTML markup is useless! So please post your (relevant) HTML code, too. Additionally it seems that you did not understand or use flexbox correctly, because any flex settings without setting `display: flex` doesn't make sense.